# How to plot (x-​1)/​(y+​2)^​1.8?

Tags: matlab, octave

I tried to plot the equation `(x-​1)/​(y+​2)^​1.8` in octave using `surf()` method. But the graph is something else.

**Here's my code:**

```
p = linspace(1,50, 100);
t = linspace(1,48,100);
ans = zeros(length(p), length(t));
ans = compute_z(p, t, ans);
figure;
surf(p, t, ans');
```

trying to compute `z = (x-​1)/​(y+​2)^​1.8` using helper function `compute_z`

```
function [ans] = compute_z(ans, p, t)
        for i = 1:length(p)
            for j = 1:length(t)
               ans(i,j) = (p(i) - 1) / (t(j)+2)^1.8;
            end
        end
```

I was trying to generate [this graph.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=(x-1)+%2F+(y+%2B+2)%5E1.8)

Comment: `ans = zeros(length(p), length(t));` is redundant. If anything, you should allocate ans inside of compute_z.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Okay.. but no change in graph.. how to i plot correct graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for your `compute_z-method` as you can you `meshgrid` and vectorisation.

```
p = linspace(1,50, 100);
t = linspace(1,48,100);

[P, T] = meshgrid(p,t); Z = (P-1) ./ (T+2).^1.8;

figure;
surf(P, T, Z);
```

(Tested in Matlab, but should work in Octave as well)

Comment: Looks like you beat me to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you define `compute_z` inputs as `ans`, `p` and `t` in that order. However, you call the function with `p`, `t` and `ans` in that order. Do you see the problem?

`ans` isn't an input to the function, just an output, so no need to list it as an input. Furthermore, don't call your variable `ans`, it's the default variable name MATLAB uses when no output variable name is specified, so is likely to be overwritten.

Here's my suggestion:

```
p = linspace(1,50, 100);
t = linspace(1,48,100);
z = zeros(length(p), length(t));
z = compute_z(p, t);
figure;
surf(p, t, z');
```

with `compute_z` defined as follows:

```
function z = compute_z(p, t)
   for i = 1:length(p)
       for j = 1:length(t)
           z(i,j) = (p(i) - 1) / (t(j)+2)^1.8;
       end
   end
```